# Why is my .NET 7.0 API returning a string without double quotes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-get, .net-7.0

I rewrote an API from .NET framework to .NET 7.0.  Some of the API endpoints return a string value. Calling the previous API would result in a response like this `"example"`. The rewritten API returns `example` without the double quotes.

This is an issue because the projects that call this API throw an error when trying to read the string value from the new API return without the double quotes. The error occurs below at ReadAsAsync:

```
var task = await client.PostAsync(new URI("APIURL"), request).ConfigureAwait(false);
result = await task.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Updating these projects to use ReadAsStringAsync does resolve the problem:

```
var task = await client.PostAsync(new URI("APIURL"), request).ConfigureAwait(false);
result = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I don't want to affect existing projects with this rewrite. Is there a way to make the API return with the double quotes? The API method looks like this:

```
public async Task<string> Get([FromQuery] string data)
```

Comment: Check out the suggested duplicate. If it does not work for you please comment - I will reopen the question.